# TG Bot (Python) having different behavior in 2 different environments

Tags: python, package, bots, telegram

I coded a TG bot that retrieves data from etherscan and format it to the user.
On the PC where I coded it everything works perfectly but now I tried to run the script on a VPS but I'm getting errors from the Bot.

I thought that this must be related to the different configuration of the two machines, I copied the requirements.txt from the 1st machine and installed the same python packages on the VPS but I got same error.

I'm running Python 3.10.4 on bot machines and using Visual Studio Code as editor/terminal.

The error that I get (which basically stucks the entire bot) is this: "Error fetching tokens transferred: string indices must be integers"

Given the fact that the codes is exactly the same on both machines, I guess that on the first one I have some library/package that handles integers in a different way?

Can't get my head around this!
Thanks for your help!